# Send data to thunderbird Add-on from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension, web-extension, thunderbird-webextensions

Is there a way to send data/messages from the chrome extension to the thunderbird add-on? I didn't find any API.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly: You want to send a message from a Chrome extension (that you've programmed yourself) to a Mozilla Thunderbird extension (that you've also programmed yourself) ? What is the purpose of these messages? Do you only want to send messages from Chrome to Thunderbird, or also in the other direction?

Comment: My chrome extension downloads a pdf file and scrapes some information from a webpage and I need to compose the message and attach pdf in thunderbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Native Messaging to send all information required to compose an e-mail (to, subject, body, attachment) from your Chrome extension to a native application, such as a Python script:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/

The Python script (which you must program yourself) then calls Thunderbird from the command line, with the appropriate command-line arguments:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird

Comment: I already tried this, but Native Messaging is not working.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I cannot help you, because I can't think of any other way to solve your problem. But perhaps someone else has a better idea.

Comment: I used Native Messaging two years back. It was working fine. But unfortunately, now it is not working. Thank you for your response and suggestion.